# MKS base 1.5 (E0 & E1) not working

Tags: extruder, marlin, stepper

I have bought two MKS base 1.5 boards. Both extruder ports are not working. I made sure the stepper motor still works and that there is nothing wrong with the Marlin firmware that I know of.

[image: Photo of wired up MKS base 1.5 board]

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the hotend above 170 °C? Because Marlin will not turn on `E0` and `E1` until it can extrude without causing damage.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. Turns out the no extrude command was uncommented and worked fine when changed the min temp on it.

Comment: Are the E0 and the E1 ports not working on *both* of the boards that you purchased?

Comment: @Chris Manning - I see that you commented on the deleted answer from pisstoff (that was converted to a comment) the following: `I figured out what was wrong. Turns out the no extrude command was uncommented and worked fine when changed the min temp on it.`  Could you post that comment as an answer and mark the answer as accepted? That would remove your question from the unanswered list, and as a beta site we need to keep that list short. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*The OP has solved the problem as read from a comment on a deleted answer. So far the OP has been reluctant to post the answer; therefore his comment is converted into a community answer.*</sub>

---

It appears that the OP had incorrectly configured his firmware considering the comment:

*"I figured out what was wrong. Turns out the no extrude command was uncommented and worked fine when changed the min temp on it."*